# publish gambas3 programs

Tags: application-development, gambas3

I have been using Gambas3 to write some User interfaces, and Ive really enjoyed the simplicity, and speed at which I can write GUIs with. Now i am ready to publish some software.  I tried walking through the publish process last night, but I ended up with a deb file with unsatisfiable dependencies.

There seems to be a wide variety of help documents for writing code,  but I haven't found anything that walks one through creating a gambas3 program and "publishing" a deb file.

I seem to have a problem in setting up the dependencies. One simple program depends on the sensors command, and gtk3 or Qt4. (either would work)
I will try to post images soon. In the mean time, can someone point me to documentation for publishing gambas3 applications as .deb files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, its not a perfect answer, I would perfer to user gambas version 3.7, but instead I uninstalled gambas version 3.7 and installed version 3.1.1. version 3.1.1 is in the repositories. Once I installed version 3.1.1, the package publishing component worked. I was able to produce a deb file, and install my software on some other systems, (after getting some dependencies).

apparently the package publishing feature is broken in version 3.7

Comment: gambas 3.4 also seems to produce operational deb files/ packages (installed from source). 3.4 has some extra features compared to v3.1, such as LCD label. version 3.4 throws an error in wheezy debian, but is fine in jessie, and 14.04 and later ubuntu.  I havent tested on the raspberry pi yet.